# Java Serversocket and Bash Connection

Tags: java, bash, tcp, connection, serversocket

I was wondering if there was a way to open a pipe between a java serversocket and a bash tcp pipe. If so how would you do this. I know how to setup the java server side but how do you open the socket connection via bash or even a windows cmd prompt. Basically i want to pipe standard input into the tcp connection and receive standard output from it.

Any examples apprechiated!

-TJ

Answer (score 0):

A ServerSocket can't do anything expect accept incoming connections, and create new Sockets which you use as endpoints (you don't use the ServerSocket for any send or recv operations). This is fine, but be aware of what side of the connection needs to accept connections. I'd assume it would be Bash since this seems to 'own' the pipe, so you'd use a Socket instead and connect that.

Comment: I would use a socket after recieveing the connection on the server socket, that would catch the request from the bash and then return a socket which would be used for communication. I basically am wondering how and if you can request a tcp connection from bash/windows cmd prompt, and if so how so. Thanks Tho :)

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the SSH tools (there are a bunch opensources, e.g., ganymade) Ref:

http://java-source.net/open-source/network-clients/ganymed-ssh-2-for-java

I have not used this particular one, but other ssh clients to do what you want.

PS: You really do not need a ServerSocket for this, but use of threads is helpful.

Comment: without a serversocket how do u catch the incoming connection?

Answer (score 0):

[Netcat](http://nc110.sourceforge.net/) is usually used to open TCP connections from a Unix shell. Bash (or any other shell I'm aware of) doesn't support it directly. There seem to exist a Windows port of Netcat too, but I haven't used it.

But it's a much better idea to just use SSH, as no special setup is required on the Java side in this case - you'll just get your standard I/O streams redirected to the SSH client automatically, with free encryption and optional compression (ssh -C) as bonuses. The disadvantage is that it would require installing an SSH server on the Java side and an SSH client on the connecting side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example - the classes Connection, Session, etc. are defined in the imports.
At the time we were using the trilead SSH, and I dont think it is available publicly any more, but you can find a lot of other libraries on the web, e.g., http://linuxmafia.com/ssh/java.html

The point is, we did not have to open a serversocket to (1) establish an SSH session, (2) do a password authentication, (3) run some command at the user's login shell, and (4) grab its stdout. I believe most SSH libraries will give you this functionality. Hope this help, - M.S.

```
public void runCommand (String uName, String pWord, String cmd) throws Exception {

    Connection conn = new Connection ("localhost");
    conn.connect();
    boolean authenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword (uName, pWord);

    if (!authenticated)
        throw new Exception ("Authentication failure");
    Session sess = connection.openSession();
    sess.execCommand (cmd);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (
                new StreamGobbler (sess.getStdout())));

    for (String s = br.readLine() ; s != null ; s = br.readLine()) {
          // do stuff with s
    }
    br.close();
    sess.close();
    conn.close();
}
```